# what is the difference between RDD lineage and DAG?

Tags: apache-spark, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am confused with RDD lineage vs DAG.

RDD Lineage is a pointer that RDD know its parents and its associated transformation and it is logical plan.

DAG is also logical plan with Graph of RDD and it transformation .

What is the difference here?